# Windows Phone 8.1 MapControl empty

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary, windows-phone-8.1

I'm beginning to develop windows phone application. 
I would like add MapControl in my app, i followed Microsoft tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741528.aspx
I have developer account, I got the Map service ApplicationID and Map service AuthenticationToken, add them in my project.

**XAML**

```
<Maps:MapControl 
x:Name="map"        
Grid.Row="1"
MapServiceToken="<token>"/>
```

with

```
xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
```

I load my project on emulator and device, but I can't display map. I have a black screen. There isn't token error.

Did I miss a step ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the XAML for your page?  Remove your map token obviously.

Comment: Please post the entire XAML markup.

Comment: Do you have the Internet capability set in Package.appxmanifest?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I try again, on simple XAML and my map is ok. There is a CacheMode="BitmapCache" in my parent Grid. When i remove it, my map is displayed...

Answer (score 0):

You mast enable(check) the Location in Capabilities tab of Package.appxmanifest